# Restrictions to simplify computation of matrix powers with SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, matrix-exponential

For a given $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ ($\in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2})$ I want to compute $A^n$ using singular value decomposition, where the intermediate terms are "nice".

Assuming we have a singular value decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^T$ we can state $A^n = (U \Sigma V^T)^n$. Assuming n is big enough, this expands into

$$A^n = (U \Sigma V^T)(U \Sigma V^T)(U \Sigma V^T)(U \Sigma V^T)^{n-3}$$

Reassociating the terms gives

$$A^n = (U \Sigma) (V^T U) \Sigma (V^T U) (\Sigma V^T)(U \Sigma V^T)^{n-3}$$

If $V^T U = I$ ($I$ being the identity matrix) this greatly simplifies to

$$A^n = U \Sigma \Sigma \dots \Sigma \Sigma V^T = U \Sigma^n V^T$$

where $\Sigma^n$ is straightforward to compute as $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix.

If more generally $V^T U = mI$ where $m \in \mathbb{R}$ is some scalar, the equation reduces to

$$A^n = U (m \Sigma)^n V^T$$

which is also fairly straightforward to compute.

---

What restrictions or conditions do I need to apply to A such that there exists a decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^T$ where $V^T U = mI$ to make computing powers of A a little nicer?

Comment: You want eigendecomposition to do this, not singular value decomposition. The two agree if $A$ is symmetric and positive-definite but not in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why the eigen decomposition over SVD? I there are $2 \times 2$ matrices which are not diagonalisable, so I cannot compute an eigen decomposition for them, but I can compute an SVD.

Comment: You always have a Jordan normal form and this is good enough for computing powers.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't understand why Jordan normal form is good enough. Can you elaborate (preferably as an answer)?

Comment: A Jordan block has the form $\lambda I + N$ where $N$ is nilpotent. In the $2 \times 2$ case $N^2 = 0$ and this gives $(\lambda I + N)^k = \lambda^k I + k \lambda^{k-1} N$. In general you can use the binomial theorem.